# Woocommerce set shipping method, get shipping cost

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my functions.php file, I need to be able to set the shipping method (there's only one for this site) and then return the cost for shipping (there are a few costs set).

I can see the `flat_rate` shipping using this:

```
foreach (WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods() as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
}
```

So it's definitely there.

Basically, I want the shipping cost returned in from an API call. I have the API routed and all that working. It calls this function that I picked up somewhere, don't recall currently:

```
function pc_get_shipping(){
  $ret = array();
    foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $method_id => $rate ){
        if( WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0] == $method_id ){
            $rate_label = $rate->label; // The shipping method label name
            $rate_cost_excl_tax = floatval($rate->cost); // The cost excluding tax
            // The taxes cost
            $rate_taxes = 0;
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $rate_tax)
                $rate_taxes += floatval($rate_tax);
            // The cost including tax
            $rate_cost_incl_tax = $rate_cost_excl_tax + $rate_taxes;

            $ret[] = array('label' => $rate_label, 'total' => WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total());
        } 
    }
  return $ret;
}
```

But that gives me just an empty array, probably because `WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates']` evaluates to an empty array.

**TL:DR**

- Guest customer shipping info is saved via `WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_1(wc_clean($value));` (etc for all values)
- Guest customer shipping info is correctly returned using `WC()->customer->get_shipping()`, so I believe it is being set correctly.
- The shipping method `flat_rate` is available via `WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods()`.
- How do I **set the shipping method for the current order** in functions.php, in a method that will be called via REST API.
- How do I **get the calculated shipping cost for the current order** in functions.php, in a method that will be called via REST API.

Comment: Does your order exist yet, when you make the API call? When are you doing your api call *(What hook are you using please)*?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm not sure - I have items in the cart... does that mean it does? And no hooks - I built a single-page shopping cart with nothing but API endpoints to connect to. So I'm doing the call from custom javascript. I have add/remove/modify items working, cart totaling, storing customer billing/shipping information, even the payment form... just haven't figured out the shipping

Comment: Ok So I republish my deleted answer, have a look to it. It should be helpful I hope.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec haven't had time to try, will update soon

Comment: Hi, Did you figure it out? I am also looking for the same with same code but no luck. Please help if you have any relevant answer.

Answer (score 3):

First on your API Response, you should need to set the cost value as custom data in `WC_Session`, with something like `(where`$value`is the response cost value from your API)`:

```
if( ! WC()->session->__isset( 'shipping_cost' ) && ! empty($value) ){
    WC()->session->set( 'shipping_cost', $value );
}
```

> you may need to ajax refresh checkout page using jQuery: **`$('body').trigger('update_checkout');`**

Then you will use this hooked function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_cost_based_on_api', 12, 2);
function shipping_cost_based_on_api( $rates, $package ){
    if( WC()->session->__isset( 'shipping_cost' ) ) {

        // Loop through the shipping taxes array
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            $has_taxes = false;

            if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ){
                // Get the initial cost
                $initial_cost = $new_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;

                // Get the new cost
                $new_cost = WC()->session->get( 'shipping_cost' );

                // Set the new cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                $taxes = [];
                // Loop through the shipping taxes array (as they can be many)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                        // Get the initial tax cost
                        $initial_tax_cost = $new_tax_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key];
                        // Get the tax rate conversion
                        $tax_rate    = $initial_tax_cost / $initial_cost;
                        // Set the new tax cost
                        $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                        $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Enabling, disabling and refreshing session shipping methods data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    $bool = true;
    if ( WC()->session->__isset('shipping_cost' ) ) $bool = false;

    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Based on: [Remove shipping cost if custom checkbox is checked in WooCommerce Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156469/remove-shipping-cost-if-custom-checkbox-is-checked-in-woocommerce-checkout/48160586#48160586)