# Show/Hide WooCommerce Shipping Rates Based on Radio Buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while now... I am trying to show or hide specific shipping rates based on a radio button option added to the Woocommerce checkout page. But I don't know anything about Ajax & JQuery which I believe it requires.

Basically if a user selects radio **option_1** it will ONLY show '**flat_rate:1**' & '**flat_rate:2**'. If the user selects radio **option_2** it will ONLY show '**flat_rate:3**' & '**flat_rate:4**'

[Click here for example of checkout screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esrWn.jpg)

Here is the code for my radio buttons displayed on checkout page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment','tc_checkout_radio_choice' );
function tc_checkout_radio_choice() {
$businesstype = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'business_residential' ),
   'required' => true,
   'options' => array(
       'option_1' => 'Business',
       'option_2' => 'Residential',
),
);
   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Select Your Business Type</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $businesstype );
   echo '</div>';
}
```

The closest example I've seen comes from an answer provided by '[LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)' in this post here: [Show/hide shipping methods based on a WooCommerce checkout field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836775/show-hide-shipping-methods-based-on-a-woocommerce-checkout-field-value/55838015#55838015)

I'm completely lost with this and the more I try to solve it, the more I get confused.

Comment: Some feed back below on the answer will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct way to show hide shipping methods based on multiple radio buttons choice on checkout page, that requires to use PHP, Ajax, jQuery and WC Session.

When **"Business"** radio button is selected (default choice), `flat_rate:3` and `flat_rate:4` shipping methods will be hidden, so customer will only be able to choose `flat_rate:1` or `flat_rate:2` shipping methods.

If **"Residential"** radio button is selected then `flat_rate:1` and `flat_rate:2` shipping methods will be hidden, so customer will only be able to choose `flat_rate:3` or `flat_rate:4` shipping methods.

The code:

```
// Display a Custom radio buttons fields for shipping options
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment','checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons' );
function checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons() {
    $field_id = 'customer_type';

    echo '<div id="customer-type-radio">';
    echo '<h3>' . __("Select Your Business Type", "woocommerce") . '</h3>';

    // Get the selected radio button value (if selected)
    $field_value = WC()->session->get( $field_id );

    // Get customer selected value on last past order
    if( empty($field_value) )
        $field_value = WC()->checkout->get_value( $field_id );

    // The default value fallback
    if( empty($field_value) )
        $field_value = 'Business';

    woocommerce_form_field( $field_id, array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'class' => array( $field_id ),
        'required' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'Business'      => __('Business', 'woocommerce'),
            'Residential'   => __('Residential', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
    ), $field_value );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Conditionally show/hide shipping methods
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_package_rates_filter_callback', 100, 2 );
function shipping_package_rates_filter_callback( $rates, $package ) {
    $customer_type = WC()->session->get( 'customer_type' ); // Get the customere type

    if ( $customer_type === 'Business' ) {
        if( isset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] ) )
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] );

        if( isset( $rates['flat_rate:4'] ) )
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:4'] );
    } 
    elseif ( $customer_type === 'Residential' ) {
        if( isset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] ) )
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );

        if( isset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] ) )
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] );
    }

    return $rates;
}

// function that gets the Ajax data
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_customer_type', 'wc_get_customer_type' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_customer_type', 'wc_get_customer_type' );
function wc_get_customer_type() {
    $field_id = 'customer_type';

    if ( isset($_POST[$field_id]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_id]) ){
        WC()->session->set($field_id, $_POST[$field_id] );
    } 

    echo json_encode( WC()->session->get( $field_id ) );

    die(); // (required)
}

// The Jquery Ajax script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_ajax_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_ajax_jquery_script() {
    $field_id = 'customer_type';

    if( WC()->session->__isset($field_id) ) 
        WC()->session->__unset($field_id);

    // Only on checkout when billing company is not defined
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        var fieldId = 'p#customer_type_field input';

        function userTypeTriggerAjax( customerType ){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'get_customer_type',
                    'customer_type': customerType,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Trigger refresh checkout
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }

        // On start
        if( $(fieldId).val() != '' ) {
            userTypeTriggerAjax( $(fieldId).val() );
        }

        // On change
        $(fieldId).change( function () {
            userTypeTriggerAjax( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Enabling, disabling and refreshing session shipping methods data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    $bool = true;

    if ( in_array( WC()->session->get('customer_type' ), ['Business', 'Residential'] ) )
        $bool = false;

    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Code based on this related threads:

- [Remove shipping cost if custom checkbox is checked in WooCommerce Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156469/remove-shipping-cost-if-custom-checkbox-is-checked-in-woocommerce-checkout/48160586#48160586)
- [Show/hide shipping methods based on a WooCommerce checkout field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836775/show-hide-shipping-methods-based-on-a-woocommerce-checkout-field-value/55838015#55838015)

Comment: Thank you! Just trying this now and it works perfectly. The conditional coding has helped me understand how this works, although I've got a lot to learn with Ajax. I've made a few changes to deselect both options on checkout and make it a required field before payment with a notification if nothing is selected. Thanks for your help, your knowledge of WooCommerce is superb!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to know how to make this a required option with an error notification before payment, this is what I did...

To de-select the radio buttons I removed the value from:

```
//if( empty($field_value) )
    $field_value = '';
```

And added this code to the checkout process at the end of the code from Loic, which adds a notification message if a radio button has not been selected:

```
// Show notice if customer does not select a business type 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'business_type_error_message' );
function business_type_error_message() {
if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['customer_type'] ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select an order type to calculate the correct shipping and proceed with your order.' ), 'error' );
}
}
```

Hope this helps others out there!