# Add custom radio buttons required fields before payment gateways in WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button, payment-gateway

Is it possible to display these following radio buttons before payment gateways in check-out page:

- "Pay at property"
  Your card won't be charged, we only need your card details to
  guarantee your booking.
- "Pay now"
  We will handle payment. You will receive a full refund if you change your mind before 31 December 2020.

Customers must choose one of these 2 buttons so one of these 2 buttons is required.

Then to make it appears in order mail for admin and customers.

If you have the solution, it will help me a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `woocommerce_review_order_before_payment` action hook to display radio buttons before payment section in WooCommerce checkout page as follow:

```
// Display a Custom radio buttons input fields before checkout available payment gateways section
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment','checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons' );
function checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons() {

    echo '<div id="custom-radio-buttons">';
    echo '<h3>' . __("Your section sub-title", "woocommerce") . '</h3>';

    // Here below set your field Id (or field key)
    $field_id = '_custom_key';

    woocommerce_form_field( $field_id, array(
        'type'     => 'radio',
        'class'    => array( 'some-class' ),
        'options'  => array(
            'First Option'    => __('First Option', 'woocommerce'),
            'Second Option'   => __('Second Option', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
        'default'  => 'First Option',
        'required' => true,
    ), WC()->checkout->get_value( $field_id ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Addition - **For a better display** you can use instead the following:

```
// Display a Custom radio buttons input fields before checkout available payment gateways section
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment','checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons' );
function checkout_customer_type_radio_buttons() {
    ## YOUR RADIO BUTTONS SETTINGS BELOW:
    $field_id = '_custom_key'; // HERE below set your field Id (or field key)
    $options = array( // HERE below set your radio button options in the array:
        __('First Option', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Second Option', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Third Option', 'woocommerce'),
    );
    $default = reset($options); // HERE set default checked option (The first one is set in here)

    echo '<div id="custom-radio-buttons">';
    echo '<h3>' . __("Your section sub-title (optional)", "woocommerce") . '</h3>';
    echo '<p class="form-row some-class validate-required" id="'.$field_id.'_field">
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">';

    $value = WC()->checkout->get_value( $field_id );
    $value = empty($value) ? $default : $value;

    // Loop through defined options array
    foreach( $options as $option ) {
        $checked = $option === $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '';

        echo '<label for="'.$field_id.'_'.$option.'"><input type="radio" class="input-radio " name="'.$field_id.'" id="'.$field_id.'_'.$option.'" value="'.$option.'"'.$checked.'> ' . $option . '</label>';
    }

    echo '</span></p></div>';
}
```

Related thread: [Show/Hide WooCommerce Shipping Rates Based on Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549494/show-hide-woocommerce-shipping-rates-based-on-radio-buttons/61552710#61552710)

Comment: It's working, thanks.
Do you know how to display the chosen choice in order mail for admin and customers please?

Comment: can you help me with this php question? please. its been long.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php

Comment: @suryavansh Sorry but I only answer some selected WooCommerce related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's work

Using form in HTML that has 2 radials and group them in the same **name** attribute for **required**. That makes the customer have to choose one of them. And then POST the value from **value** attribute, so you can use the value for the next process you want

```html
<form action="/page.php" method="POST">
    <label for="payAtProperty">
    <input type="radio" id="payAtProperty" name="payMethod" value="method-1" required>
    "Pay at property" <br> "Your card won't be charged, we only need your card details to guarantee your booking."          
    </label><br> 
    <label for="payNow">
    
    <input type="radio" id="payNow" name="payMethod" value="method-2">
    "Pay now" <br> We will handle payment. You will receive a full refund if you change your mind before 31 December 2020.
  </label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Aeolus,

Unfortunately, I need a php code for functions.php (WordPress) :-( Thank you anyways!

Comment: HI Georgy Bouras.
Hope you get the solution soon sir.